# how use raster data directly with openlayers

Tags: raster, openlayers

I am currently using qgis2web to set up a WebGIS project for which I would like to avoid a WebGIS server. I cannot find a way to convert my raster data in a way that it keeps its information (1 band 32 bit float). If I use the qgis2Web export function, it gets converted into a .png without the original values.  I tried to search a file format that is supported by Openlayers or Leaflet that would retain the original values but could only find the option to use WMS.

Comment: Not sure a WMS will help in your situation in any case.

Comment: I have the possibility to use a ArcGIS server, so I am not limited to WMS. I found an OL example to get information from a WMS, so it might be enough for the first project.

Comment: You could have a WMS give a tiff, but that's no good for an OpenLayers app. You could configure a WCS if you want to query a raster, but you have the problem of no direct support in OL for WCS and issue of output format

Answer (score 1):

The underlying issue is that webmaps are webpages, and webpages have more limited support for rasters, focused almost completely on visual appearance, not underlying data. That's why qgis2web converts rasters to PNGs. If it didn't, there is no guarantee that the rasters would display. Sorry not to have a solution.